# Failed to download a package from github in Rstudio

Tags: r, github

When I want to download a package from github by Rstudio, the error message is like this:

*devtools::install_github("akoyabio/phenoptr")*

> Downloading GitHub repo akoyabio/phenoptr@HEAD
> Error: Failed to install 'phenoptr' from GitHub:
> Line starting 'SystemRequir ...' is malformed!

And then I try to download the package to my PC and install package from local position. The error message appear again.

*devtools::install_local("D:\phenoptr-master.zip")*

> Error: Failed to install 'phenoptr-master.zip' from local:
> Line starting 'SystemRequir ...' is malformed!

I don't know why this happened. If anyone could give me some advice to solve the problem?
Thank you very much.

Mengfei Wang

Comment: You should submit a bug report in the github page of the project.

Comment: hmm, works for me; and i don't see any `SystemRequirements` field at all in the repo?  (I used `remotes::install_github(...)` but that shouldn't be any different ...)

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  I tried remotes::install_github(...), but it didn't work, just like you said. I will try if there is any other ways to solve it. Thank you :)

Comment: I think I ran into a relate issue today: https://github.com/ManuelHentschel/vscDebugger/issues/171

Answer (score 0):

The problem was probably caused by a faulty locale setting. Try setting your locale by running

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","en_US.UTF-8")
```

or

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
```

before calling `install_github()`.